# Found a reference to "Local" Error but no definition of what it is

Tags: excel, vba

I found a reference to `On Local Error GoTo Class_Initialize_Err` in an MS [article](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/198465). When I add the `Local` keyword to my Excel VBA code, the compiler accepts it. However, I cannot find any reference to this keyword either in the Help documentation nor on the web.

Does anyone know what `Local` refers to and/or what it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HansV from Windows Secrets](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/106356-On-Local-Error-%28Access-2000-VBA%29):

> `On Local Error` is a remnant from older versions of BASIC (before Visual Basic for Applications). In current versions it acts the same as `On Error` and there is no particular reason to use it any more.